# How can I Use Connected Animation in WPF App like UWP

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp

I want to implement UWP connected animation in my WPF app. like this......

[image]

Is it possible? If it is then how can I do it?

Comment: You can set the from without set the to to do it.

Comment: I cannot understand your comment!

Comment: Could you see the Chinese post? [Make ConnectedAnimation in WPF - walterlv](https://walterlv.com/post/connected-animation-of-wpf.html )

Comment: You can use the Google translate to translate the post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using Walterlv.Annotations;

namespace Walterlv.Demo.Media.Animation
{
    public class ConnectedAnimation
    {
        internal ConnectedAnimation([NotNull] string key, [NotNull] UIElement source, [NotNull] EventHandler completed)
        {
            Key = key ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(key));
            _source = source ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
            _reportCompleted = completed ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(completed));
        }

        public string Key { get; }
        private readonly UIElement _source;
        private readonly EventHandler _reportCompleted;

        public bool TryStart([NotNull] UIElement destination)
        {
            return TryStart(destination, Enumerable.Empty<UIElement>());
        }

        public bool TryStart([NotNull] UIElement destination, [NotNull] IEnumerable<UIElement> coordinatedElements)
        {
            if (destination == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(destination));
            }
            if (coordinatedElements == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(coordinatedElements));
            }
            if (Equals(_source, destination))
            {
                return false;
            }
            // showing the animation?

            // ready to connect the animation。
            var adorner = ConnectedAnimationAdorner.FindFrom(destination);
            var connectionHost = new ConnectedVisual(_source, destination);
            adorner.Children.Add(connectionHost);

            var storyboard = new Storyboard();
            var animation = new DoubleAnimation(0.0, 1.0, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10.6)))
            {
                EasingFunction = new CubicEase {EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseInOut},
            };
            Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, connectionHost);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath(ConnectedVisual.ProgressProperty.Name));
            storyboard.Children.Add(animation);
            storyboard.Completed += (sender, args) =>
            {
                _reportCompleted(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                //destination.ClearValue(UIElement.VisibilityProperty);
                adorner.Children.Remove(connectionHost);
            };
            //destination.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            storyboard.Begin();

            return true;
        }

        private class ConnectedVisual : DrawingVisual
        {
            public static readonly DependencyProperty ProgressProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
                "Progress", typeof(double), typeof(ConnectedVisual),
                new PropertyMetadata(0.0, OnProgressChanged), ValidateProgress);

            public double Progress
            {
                get => (double) GetValue(ProgressProperty);
                set => SetValue(ProgressProperty, value);
            }

            private static bool ValidateProgress(object value) =>
                value is double progress && progress >= 0 && progress <= 1;

            private static void OnProgressChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                ((ConnectedVisual) d).Render((double) e.NewValue);
            }

            public ConnectedVisual([NotNull] Visual source, [NotNull] Visual destination)
            {
                _source = source ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
                _destination = destination ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(destination));

                _sourceBrush = new VisualBrush(source) {Stretch = Stretch.Fill};
                _destinationBrush = new VisualBrush(destination) {Stretch = Stretch.Fill};
            }

            private readonly Visual _source;
            private readonly Visual _destination;
            private readonly Brush _sourceBrush;
            private readonly Brush _destinationBrush;
            private Rect _sourceBounds;
            private Rect _destinationBounds;

            protected override void OnVisualParentChanged(DependencyObject oldParent)
            {
                if (VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(this) == null)
                {
                    return;
                }

                var sourceBounds = VisualTreeHelper.GetContentBounds(_source);
                if (sourceBounds.IsEmpty)
                {
                    sourceBounds = VisualTreeHelper.GetDescendantBounds(_source);
                }
                _sourceBounds = new Rect(
                    _source.PointToScreen(sourceBounds.TopLeft),
                    _source.PointToScreen(sourceBounds.BottomRight));
                _sourceBounds = new Rect(
                    PointFromScreen(_sourceBounds.TopLeft),
                    PointFromScreen(_sourceBounds.BottomRight));

                var destinationBounds = VisualTreeHelper.GetContentBounds(_destination);
                if (destinationBounds.IsEmpty)
                {
                    destinationBounds = VisualTreeHelper.GetDescendantBounds(_destination);
                }
                _destinationBounds = new Rect(
                    _destination.PointToScreen(destinationBounds.TopLeft),
                    _destination.PointToScreen(destinationBounds.BottomRight));
                _destinationBounds = new Rect(
                    PointFromScreen(_destinationBounds.TopLeft),
                    PointFromScreen(_destinationBounds.BottomRight));
            }

            private void Render(double progress)
            {
                var bounds = new Rect(
                    (_destinationBounds.Left - _sourceBounds.Left) * progress + _sourceBounds.Left,
                    (_destinationBounds.Top - _sourceBounds.Top) * progress + _sourceBounds.Top,
                    (_destinationBounds.Width - _sourceBounds.Width) * progress + _sourceBounds.Width,
                    (_destinationBounds.Height - _sourceBounds.Height) * progress + _sourceBounds.Height);

                using (var dc = RenderOpen())
                {
                    dc.DrawRectangle(_sourceBrush, null, bounds);
                    dc.PushOpacity(progress);
                    dc.DrawRectangle(_destinationBrush, null, bounds);
                    dc.Pop();
                }
            }
        }

        private class ConnectedAnimationAdorner : Adorner
        {
            private ConnectedAnimationAdorner([NotNull] UIElement adornedElement)
                : base(adornedElement)
            {
                Children = new VisualCollection(this);
                IsHitTestVisible = false;
            }

            internal VisualCollection Children { get; }

            protected override int VisualChildrenCount => Children.Count;

            protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index) => Children[index];

            protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
            {
                foreach (var child in Children.OfType<UIElement>())
                {
                    child.Arrange(new Rect(child.DesiredSize));
                }
                return finalSize;
            }

            internal static ConnectedAnimationAdorner FindFrom([NotNull] Visual visual)
            {
                if (Window.GetWindow(visual)?.Content is UIElement root)
                {
                    var layer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(root);
                    if (layer != null)
                    {
                        var adorner = layer.GetAdorners(root)?.OfType<ConnectedAnimationAdorner>().FirstOrDefault();
                        if (adorner == null)
                        {
                            adorner = new ConnectedAnimationAdorner(root);
                            layer.Add(adorner);
                        }
                        return adorner;
                    }
                }
                throw new InvalidOperationException("指定的 Visual 尚未连接到可见的视觉树中，找不到用于承载动画的容器。");
            }

            internal static void ClearFor([NotNull] Visual visual)
            {
                if (Window.GetWindow(visual)?.Content is UIElement root)
                {
                    var layer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(root);
                    var adorner = layer?.GetAdorners(root)?.OfType<ConnectedAnimationAdorner>().FirstOrDefault();
                    if (adorner != null)
                    {
                        layer.Remove(adorner);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How to use?

```
private int index;

private void AnimationButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    BeginConnectedAnimation((UIElement)sender, ConnectionDestination);
}

private async void BeginConnectedAnimation(UIElement source, UIElement destination)
{
    var service = ConnectedAnimationService.GetForCurrentView(this);
    service.PrepareToAnimate($"Test{index}", source);    

    var animation = service.GetAnimation($"Test{index}");
    animation?.TryStart(destination);

    // use different Key when click。
    index++;
}
```

[image: Preview]

See https://walterlv.com/post/connected-animation-of-wpf.html

Comment: @Shakir Ahmed The post posted above has only a few non-English parts, you can try to use Google Translate to translate it into an English version to read. I'm the author of the post and if you have problems reading the translated version, please contact me and I'll write an English version.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Yes, I translated it.